# Folder Permission settings

Tags: powershell, permissions, directory

Im executing the below command for creating the folder in remote servers. I have received an error message for Access control list while setting the permission to new folder (Team in F drive) , could you help me to resolve this.

```
$acl=Get-Acl "\\9018\F$\Team Data"$path=md "F:\Team" | set-acl -aclobject $acl
Invoke-Command -ComputerName (Get-Content C:\Server.txt) -ScriptBlock {
param($acl,$path)
} -ArgumentList $acl,$path
```

**Error Message:**

```
set-acl : The security identifier is not allowed to be the owner of this object.
At F:\folder.ps1:2 char:26
+ $path=md "F:\Team" | set-acl -aclobject $acl
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (F:\CDS Team:String) [Set-Acl], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-ACL` will get every security permission on the object so when you pipe it to `Set-ACL` you're possibly telling it to set every permission.

What you can try is changing

`$acl=Get-Acl "\9018\F$\Team Data"$path=md "F:\Team"`

to

`$acl=(Get-Item "\9018\F$\Team Data").GetAccessControl('Access') | Set-ACL -Path F:\Team`

I tested this with a folder on my virtual server using the code below (which worked) so maybe you can fiddle with the code and get it working:

```
$acl=(Get-Item \\core\testshare$).GetAccessControl('Access')
$acl | Set-Acl -Path \\core\changeacl
```

Your code suggests you might need to do this for more then one server, what you can do to accomplish this is put a foreach before your code like so

```
$servers = Get-Content C:\Servers.txt
ForEach ($server in $servers)
{
    $acl=(Get-Item \\core\testshare$).GetAccessControl('Access')
    $acl | Set-Acl -Path "$server\Team"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Bluecakes , i've created command like this and it works fine. To retain the access control list and owner permission we need to use the New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("domainname", "ownername")

```
$j=Invoke-Command -ComputerName (Get-Content F:\ExchServerlist.txt) -ScriptBlock {md   "F:\Team"} -asjob
$servers = Get-Content F:\ExchServerlist.txt
ForEach ($server in $servers)
{
$ChkFile = "\\$server\f$\Team" 
$FileExists = Test-Path $ChkFile
If ($FileExists -eq $True) 
{
Write-Host "File Exists/Created in $server"
Write-Host "Waiting to complete" $server
$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("domainname", "ownername")
$objfile =  Get-Acl "\\9018\f$\Team Data"
$objFile.SetOwner($objUser)
$path = Set-Acl -aclobject $objFile -path "\\$server\f$\Team"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {param($objUser,$objfile,$path)} -ArgumentList $objuser,$objfile,$path -asjob
}
else {$j | wait-job -Timeout 30}
}
```